# Finite subgroups of $SL_2({\mathbb R})\times SL_2({{\mathbb R}})$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, geometric-group-theory, lattices-in-lie-groups

Is there a classification of finite subgroups of $SL_2({\mathbb R})\times SL_2({{\mathbb R}})$?

For instance we have all cyclic groups and all direct products of two cyclic groups.  Are there any others?

Comment: Every finite subgroup lies in a maximal compact subgroup, so it amounts to classify finite subgroups of the torus $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^2$, and hence of its torsion subgroup $(\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z})^2$. In conclusion, *up to isomorphism* we precisely get all products of two finite cyclic groups.

Comment: Do you want to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every finite subgroup lies in a maximal compact subgroup, so it amounts to classify finite subgroups of the torus $(\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z})^2$, and hence of its torsion subgroup $(\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z})^2$. In conclusion, up to isomorphism we precisely get all direct products of two finite cyclic groups.

Comment: Thank you very much!